# Unable to connect Internet to Xubuntu 14.04 with wired connection

Tags: networking, system-installation, xubuntu

Just installed Xubuntu 14.04 from usb, installed okay except that I cannot connect to internet.

- I'm connected via a Solwise Homeplug (Ethernet over wiring).
- Xubuntu says I have 'Wired connection 1' but 'Ethernet Network' is greyed out
- ipconfig lists a section for 'etho' and 'lo'
- I have a Mac and a PC connected to the same homeplug and their internet connection is fine
- During installation it also complained I have no internet access.

Previously I was running Xubuntu 12.10 and that was working fine until yesterday when it also lost internet connection and then wouldn't start after reboot. It is for this reason that I installed Xubuntu 14.04 figuring a new installation would resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`ipconfig lists a section for 'etho' and 'lo'`
You you have an IP in the eth0 entry? Perhaps your machine doesn't get a DHCP IP...

Comment: unilke the lo section it has a line for inet6 but not inet (4) could that be the problem

Comment: How do I test this dhcp thereom (noobie linux user)

Comment: Its okay, I turned off and on my other solwise plug downstairs and now working, FWIW ifconfig is also showing an inet (4) address now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)